# boost::log::record_view assignment operator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

```
#include <boost/log/core/record_view.hpp>

struct A
{
   boost::log::record_view view;
};

int main()
{
   const A a = {};
   A b;
   b = a;

   const boost::log::record_view r;
   boost::log::record_view rr;
   rr = r;
}
```

The second is compiled, while first is not. The compiler says, implicit copy-assignment operator is in form `A& A::operator=(A&)`, but I have no idea why the second is compiled in this case. I can of course write manually overloaded `operator =`, but I want to know the cause of this behavior.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3278f169d6af942f)

It looks like the problem is only with C++98, so only with move emulation in boost.

```
BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE(record_view)
```

where

```
   #define BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE(TYPE)\
      public:\
      TYPE& operator=(TYPE &t)\
      {  this->operator=(static_cast<const ::boost::rv<TYPE> &>(const_cast<const TYPE &>(t))); return *this;}\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone, problem is, that actually `record_view` has 3 assignment operators.
One is from `BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE` in the form

```
TYPE& operator=(TYPE &t)\
      {  this->operator=(static_cast<const ::boost::rv<TYPE> &>(const_cast<const TYPE &>(t))); return *this;}\
```

And the other two are:

```
/*!
 * Copy assignment
 */
record_view& operator= (BOOST_COPY_ASSIGN_REF(record_view) that) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    m_impl = that.m_impl;
    return *this;
}

/*!
 * Move assignment. Source record contents unspecified after the operation.
 */
record_view& operator= (BOOST_RV_REF(record_view) that) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    m_impl.swap(that.m_impl);
    return *this;
}
```

The second code compiled due to the second operator, where `BOOST_COPY_ASSIGN_REF` is

```
   #define BOOST_COPY_ASSIGN_REF(TYPE)\
      const ::boost::rv< TYPE >& \
```

But the compiler will generate `operator =` in the form `const T&` only if

N4296 12.8/18.2

> for all the non-static data members of X that are of a class type M
>   (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment
>   operator whose parameter is of type const M&, const volatile M& or M.

So, only the first assignment operator of `record_view` will be checked.